# Add a value to an JSON array object

Tags: jquery, json

I have an array that looks like this

```
[{
    "Inventory": {
        "dashboard_id": "Inventory",
        "filter_by": "Location",
        "yAxis": "Quantity",
        "title": "",
        "chart_type": "-------Select-------",
        "mainchart": "Yes"
    },
    "Quality": {
        "dashboard_id": "Quality",
        "filter_by": "Location",
        "yAxis": "SampleNo",
        "title": "",
        "chart_type": "-------Select-------",
        "mainchart": "Yes"
    }
}]
```

I need to add more values into each object. How do I ADD to an existing array so it might look something like this

```
{
    "Inventory": [{
        "dashboard_id": "Inventory",
        "filter_by": "Location",
        "yAxis": "Quantity",
        "title": "",
        "chart_type": "-------Select-------",
        "mainchart": "Yes"
    }, {
        "dashboard_id": "Inventory",
        "filter_by": "Location",
        "yAxis": "Quantity",
        "title": "",
        "chart_type": "-------Select-------",
        "mainchart": "Yes"
    }],
    "Quality": {
        "dashboard_id": "Quality",
        "filter_by": "Location",
        "yAxis": "SampleNo",
        "title": "",
        "chart_type": "-------Select-------",
        "mainchart": "Yes"
    }
}
```

I add into the array using `nestedData[dashId] = data;`

Where dashId consist of `Quality`, 'Inventory', etc.

data is

```
{
    "dashboard_id": "Inventory",
    "filter_by": "Location",
    "yAxis": "Quantity",
    "title": "",
    "chart_type": "-------Select-------",
    "mainchart": "Yes"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a new `Object` using the literal syntax, which contains the desired arrays and assigns the objects from the source array to the respective property in the object.

```
var arr = [{
    "Inventory": {
        "dashboard_id": "Inventory",
        "filter_by": "Location",
        "yAxis": "Quantity",
        "title": "",
        "chart_type": "-------Select-------",
        "mainchart": "Yes"
    },
    "Quality": {
        "dashboard_id": "Quality",
        "filter_by": "Location",
        "yAxis": "SampleNo",
        "title": "",
        "chart_type": "-------Select-------",
        "mainchart": "Yes"
    }
}];

var obj = {Inventory:[arr[0].Inventory], Quality:[arr[0].Quality]};
obj.Inventory.push({
    "dashboard_id": "Inventory",
    "filter_by": "Location",
    "yAxis": "Quantity",
    "title": "",
    "chart_type": "-------Select-------",
    "mainchart": "Yes"
});

console.log(obj);
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/vJjSX/